# Error in Moodle "you don't have permission to view this list of courses in moodle"

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-theme

When i try to go Main page of the Moodle (Version 3.6) its display "you don't have permission to view this list of courses". Then i refresh several time only its display the home page. after that when i try to access login section again its display "you don't have permission to view this list of courses" error message.again after several refreshing its display the login page. I have attached screenshot here....can anyone please help me with the problem.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMLeA.png)
[Full Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkUHs.png)

I did below Things

1.) Site administration / Users / Permissions / Define roles / Authenticated user
Click "Edit" and search:
"View list of courses you are not enrolled in [moodle/category:viewcourselist]"
and put "Allow"

2.) purged the caches

---

@Russell Moodle version is 3.6

Courses are not hidden.

Below I have attached the Full trace of the error

[Full Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkUHs.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Is this even a programming-related problem?

Comment: "Below I have attached the Full trace of the error" - please never share text output hidden in a screenshot. Also, please share the code involved

Answer (score 0):

Is it hidden? There's also the capability `moodle/course:viewhiddencourses`

Switch on debugging to developer level, then update your question with the full trace

Site administration > Development > Debugging

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Debugging#Debug_messages

Please also specify which version of Moodle you are using

Comment: Moodle version 3.6

Comment: Can you specify the exact Moodle version, that trace of code doesn't match 3.6.10, which is the latest update for 3.6